# How to detect windows 10S in a Desktop bridge win32 Store App

Tags: uwp, desktop-bridge

I have a win32 desktop bridge converted Microsoft Store app. I can make uwp calls through a DLL as documented by Microsoft. How can I detect Windows 10s environment so that I can disable certain features that do not work on Windows 10s.

Note that other question, answers on the same topic do not help me as they advise calling getProductInfo from a kernel dll which is not possible for a desktop bridge win32 app or a uwp app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this may help.

You should use [GetProductInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getproductinfo?redirectedfrom=MSDN) Win32 API call and check for return value `PRODUCT_CLOUD (0x000000B2)` and `PRODUCT_CLOUDN (0x000000B3)`. That 2 values are the SKU detection codes for Windows 10 S.

Comment: Thanks but it's not clear what parameters I should be passing to GetProductInfo. I tried passing 6, 3, 0, 0 and got return value as decimal 49.

Comment: I think I'm just using a Windows 10s virtual machine created based on this article, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-test-windows-s Hence, it returns 49. Maybe, I will need to get a real Windows 10s/11s installation to test how this function works.

Comment: To test this, I will need to actually install Windows 10s. I found an old 10s Installer on microsoft site: Windows10SInstaller5932.exe that supposedly works for Windows 10 1703. Does it still work for latest Windows 10 builds?